# How to solve (step-by-step) this trig. equation below?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos{2x}\cdot\cos{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}=\sin{2x}\cdot\sin{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$$

The root of my struggle with this problem is that I know (said by Wolframalpha) that it can be solved, I just can't find a "nice" way to write it down, step-by-step...

Comment: Hint: What is $\cos A \cos B -\sin A \sin B$?

Comment: Now I am literally banging my head against the wall for missing that. * embarrassed *

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recognize that subtracting $$\sin{2x}\sin{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$$from both sides will show the recognizable equation of $$\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}-\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}=\cos\left(\alpha+\beta\right)$$ now that you see this equation you can then realize that when you subtracted $$\sin{2x}\sin{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$$ from both sides the equation became: $$\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}-\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}=0$$ This means that $$\cos{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}=0$$ This is recognizable to the basic cosine $$\cos{90^\circ}=0$$ Therefore all you have to do is solve $$2\mathit{x}+\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$$
Where $n$ is any integer. Solving this algebraically shows that $$\mathit{x}=\frac{2\pi}{9}+n\frac{\pi}{3}$$ Tell me if I should clarify further.

Comment: Thank you very much! it actually hit me with the comment of player3236 above... I'd really like to mark yours the "official" answer but could you then please add periodicity to your final result (not to confuse any blind idiots -- like myself -- even further...)? Thanks again!